# Is there something similar to sessionStorage but with multidimensional keys?

Tags: javascript, html, session-variables, session-storage

I'd like to save off values of a tree-like structure locally, then retrieve them based on user interaction.  After some research, I found that `sessionStorage` (or `localStorage`) might be a good way to go about doing this.  But I'm having trouble saving nested data.

Normally you have:

```
sessionStorage['key'] = 'someString';
```

I tried to implement something like:

```
sessionStorage['key1'] = [];
sessionStorage['key1']['key2'] = 'someString';
```

but I got an `undefined` error.

I've checked out few other storage libraries, but they only offer that single key-value pair option. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use JSON to serialise the nested data into a string, then decode it when you need to access it as an object...

```
var nested = {some:{nested:'object'}}
var asJson = JSON.stringify(nested)
sessionStorage['data'] = asJson
var asObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['data'])
```

Comment: I have 3 objects I want to save per key, but I never thought to combin e them into one, then serialize. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From developer.mozilla.com:

> The DOM Storage mechanism is a means through which string key/value
>   pairs can be securely stored and later retrieved for use.

Hence I think you cannot store array/dictionary directly in session storage. I highly suggest you that check this link out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: you cannot do Key=String but the value can be stored as Object- Check the link : http://www.diveintojavascript.com/tutorials/web-storage-tutorial-creating-an-address-book-application